# 3D Gridded Plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, anaconda

I am looking for a library. I have 3D gridded data that I want to plot using Python. When I want to plot 2D gridded data I use matplotlib's `matshow`:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import matshow, show
matshow(some_data)
show()
```

[image: matshow example]

But now I have a 3D version of this sort of raster data, and I want to be able to plot boxes (cubes) stacked in 3D space. Ideally, this would be solvable using matplotlib but my guess is the solution will be in a different library (hopefully, something in Anaconda).

Comment: I would actually have no idea where to begin with this but maybe there is something in the `mayavi` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Bas Jansen, you can do this with mayavi as follows,

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

ncubes = 12
x = np.arange(0,ncubes)
y = np.arange(0,ncubes)
z = np.arange(0,ncubes)
value = np.arange(0,ncubes)
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, value, mode='cube',scale_mode='none', scale_factor=1.0)

mlab.show()
```

You may need to open the script with `ipython --pylab=qt` so the window persists. The resulting figure is,

[image]

You could do this in `matplotlib`, probably using patch objects to build up a cube and colour the patches as needed, however for 3D plotting, `mayavi` is generally easier/better.